# How to force 24 hour time in Telerik's RadDateTimePicker and keep the date formatting as "d"?

Tags: asp.net, internationalization, telerik, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I'm using Telerik's [RadDateTimePicker](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) to select the time of the event in my web-app (ASP.NET, .NET 3.5).

The application is targeting multiple countries, my **date** formatting is taken care of based on users' CultureInfo.

There's one problem, I need the **time** part of the date/time to **ALWAYS** show in 24 hour format, no matter what CultureInfo is in the Thread.

For 'en-US' it should show 9/23/2010 13:00
For 'ru-RU' it should show 23/9/2010 13:00

Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't force date format; there are some reasons why .Net supports locales (via CultureInfo). However, if you insist on doing that try playing with Culture, DateFormat and TimeFormat. I don't know much about these controls, but from what I seen on their website, this is the way to alter behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker Culture="nl" />
```

Change culture according to country.

Or:

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker DateTimeText="{Binding EndDateTime, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}}"  />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `RadDateTimePicker.TimeView.TimeFormat = "HH:mm";`

Answer (score 1):

```
RadDateTimePicker.TimeView.TimeFormat = "HH:mm tt";
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the newest 2017 controls and find it to be very simple. In the xml I include

TimeView-TimeFormat="HH:mm"

So a full time picker might look like this

```
    <telerik:RadTimePicker ID="txtCloseMeetingEnd" runat="server" EnableTyping="true" DateInput-EmptyMessage="End Time" TimeView-Culture="en-gb" TimeView-Interval="00:30:00" DateInput-DateFormat="HH:mm" TimeView-TimeFormat="HH:mm"></telerik:RadTimePicker>
```

This example allows for military time with a drop-down that has 30 minute intervals. This site is for US english language users but I am using the Culture "en-gb" because in older versions of the control I found that the Great Britain (GB) setting allowed me to show the items in the drop-down list as military time. It seems to be unnecessary in the new controls but I have not taken the time to test it thoroughly